# Insert N matrices with 3 dimensions to a new variable

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, signal-processing

I need to insert 3-dimensional matrices into a new variable.
I'm trying to do that by:
Creating a 4-dimensional matrix and by promoting the fourth dimension saving the three dimensions respectively.

Sample code:

```
from python_speech_features import mfcc  
import numpy as np

X = np.zeros((0,0,0,0),float) #4-dimensional - (0, 0, 0, 0)  
ii = 0  

    for ii in range 1000:  
      data, fs = sf.read(curfile[ii])  
      sig = mfcc(data, fs, winstep=winstep,winlen=winlen,nfft=1024) #size - (49, 13)  
      sig = sig[:, :, np.newaxis] #add third-dimensional - (49, 13, 1)  
      X[:,:,:,ii] = sig
```

Error:

> IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 3 with size 0

Someone can help me with that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not creating array in right way. You cannot insert value in axis which have zero length at least specify some length for axis

```
X = np.zeros((10, 10, 10,1000), float)
print(X.shape)
# (10, 10, 10, 1000)
```

Now you can set value in whatever axis you want by simply,

```
X[:, :, :, 2] = 1
# this will simply set value of 3rd axis's 3rd element to 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use np.stack (i think it is the best way of doing it) or create the initial array in its final size:

np.zeros((49,13,1,1000), float)

In your case